# Conditionally apply re.I

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have the following pattern:

```
if is_ci:
    re.match(token_pattern, substring, flag=re.I)
else:
    re.match(token_pattern, substring)
```

Is there a way to conditionally set the `re.I` (or any other flag) directly? For example, something like:

```
re.match(token_pattern, substring, re.I = is_ci)
```

I know there is [`NOFLAG`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.NOFLAG) in py3.11 but I am on py3.9.

Answer (score 1):

The `re` flags are bits that can be anded together and the `NOFLAG` just means  `0`. So, you can set the flags to 0 when you don't want any and use `re.I` when you do (which, is actually the value `2`):

```
re.match(token_pattern, substring, flags=re.I if is_ci else 0)
```

Or, you can also conditionally define `re.NOFLAG` at the top of the program to use:

```
re.NOFLAG = 0

...

re.match(token_pattern, substring, flags=re.I if is_ci else re.NOFLAG)
```